# Github Actions Build Docker Image on ARM64 (macos-latest-xlarge)

Tags: docker, macos, github, dockerfile, github-actions

Created a github action for building a docker image for arm64 platform to build it fast (no emulation) I use `macos-latest-xlarge` arm64 machine

An example github action code is as follows:

```
name: Mac OS Issue
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  macos_issue:
    name: Check Issue
    runs-on: macos-latest-xlarge
    steps:
      - name: Check Issue
        id: check_issue
        run: |
          set +e
          brew install docker docker-buildx
          docker --version
          echo "FROM ubuntu:latest" > Dockerfile
          docker build --no-cache -t test .
```

when ran it fails with the following error

```
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I tried emulation with macos-latest it is extremely slow.
So It must be arm64 machine

Comment: Isn't docker pre-installed on those machines?

Comment: unfortunately, no

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1456#issuecomment-1676495453

Comment: getting ...
hostagent socket created at /Users/runner/.colima/_lima/colima/ha.sock"
Driver stopped due to error: signal: abort trap
Shutting down the host agent"
failed to exit SSH master"
Shutting down QEMU with ACPI"
Failed to remove SSH binding for port 49201"
failed to open the QMP socket /Users/runner/.colima/_lima/colima/qmp.sock\ forcibly killing QEMU"
QEMU has already exited"
exiting, status={Running:false Degraded:false Exiting:true Errors:[] SSHLocalPort:0} (hint: see \"/Users/runner/.colima/_lima/colima/ha.stderr.log\")"
creating and starting': exit status 1"

Comment: See: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/2150 Docker is not preinstalled on mac due to license restrictions.

Comment: Side question: since you're looking for speed, you might want to try [FlyCI](www.flyci.net)'s M2 runners. They're faster and quite affordable, compared to GitHub's.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your GitHub Actions workflow, you are trying to build a Docker image on a macOS runner (`macos-latest-xlarge`), which seems to be an ARM64 machine. But, you see an error indicating that the Docker daemon is not running.

```bash
+---------------------+        +------------------+
| GitHub Actions      |        | macOS ARM64      |
| Workflow            |  SSH   | Runner           |
|                     |------->| (macos-latest-   |
| - Build Docker Image|        | xlarge)          |
| - ARM64 Platform    |        |                  |
+---------------------+        +------------------+
```

Similar to the comments, I would first check that Docker is properly installed and running on the macOS runner. You might need to start the Docker service explicitly, as it is not started by default on macOS runners.

The GitHub Action code would then be (as an alternative to the [colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) approach mentioned in [issue 1456](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1456#issuecomment-1676495453)):

```yaml
name: Mac OS Issue
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  macos_issue:
    name: Check Issue
    runs-on: macos-latest-xlarge
    steps:
      - name: Install Docker
        run: |
          brew install --cask docker

      - name: Start Docker
        run: |
          # Start Docker.app if not already running
          if ! pgrep -f Docker.app; then
            open -a /Applications/Docker.app
            # Wait for Docker to be ready
            while ! docker info >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done
          fi

      - name: Build Docker Image
        run: |
          echo "FROM ubuntu:latest" > Dockerfile
          docker build --no-cache -t test .
```

The `open --background -a Docker` command starts Docker in the background. I have seen that approach in, for instance, "[Building and Monitoring a Kubernetes Cluster with Kind and AppDynamics](https://medium.com/@abhimanyubajaj98/building-and-monitoring-a-kubernetes-cluster-with-kind-and-appdynamics-cefe2e74a18f)" from [Abhimanyu Bajaj](https://github.com/Abhimanyu9988)
The loop `while ! docker system info > /dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done` waits for the Docker daemon to become ready.

---

> I run the commands one by one script connecting to the mac instance via https://github.com/lhotari/action-upterm: the `Docker.app` is running but the `docker info` returns the error
>
> ```
> ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock.
> ```

That error should indicate that the Docker CLI is unable to communicate with the Docker daemon. That could be because of the Docker daemon not running, or because there is a permissions issue.

Since you have confirmed that `Docker.app` is running on the macOS instance via the `action-upterm`, make sure the Docker daemon itself is active. You can try restarting the Docker service.

On macOS, the current user may not have the necessary permissions to interact with the Docker daemon. Check and modify the permissions if needed. (`id -a`: look at least for a group named `docker`)

The GitHub Action code would be:

```yaml
name: Mac OS Issue
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  macos_issue:
    name: Check Issue
    runs-on: macos-latest-xlarge
    steps:
      - name: Install and Start Docker
        run: |
          brew install --cask docker
          open -a Docker

      - name: Check Docker Daemon
        run: |
          # Make sure Docker Daemon is running
          if ! docker info; then
            echo "Restarting Docker..."
            osascript -e 'quit app "Docker"'
            sleep 5
            open -a Docker
            # Wait for Docker to be ready
            while ! docker info >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done
          fi

      - name: Build Docker Image
        run: |
          echo "FROM ubuntu:latest" > Dockerfile
          docker build --no-cache -t test .
```

Since you can access the macOS instance via action-upterm, use this access to manually check Docker's status and troubleshoot interactively. And inspect the Docker logs for clues. Make sure no environment variables are interfering with Docker's operation.

---

> The `Docker.app` is running but the `docker info` never succeeds

Even though `Docker.app` appears to be running, it might not be fully functional. Check its status and logs for any issues.

```yaml
- name: Troubleshoot Docker
  run: |
    # Checking Docker.app status
    ps aux | grep Docker.app

    # Checking Docker daemon log
    cat /var/log/docker.log || echo "Docker log not found"

    # Reset Docker to factory defaults (if possible through CLI)
    # Specific command depends on Docker version and setup

    # Reinstalling Docker
    brew uninstall --cask docker
    brew install --cask docker
    open -a Docker

    # Wait and check if docker info works
    while ! docker info >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done
```

Since you have interactive access to the macOS instance via action-upterm, use it to perform these troubleshooting steps manually. That can provide immediate feedback and a better understanding of what is happening.

The System logs on the macOS runner might provide more details about what is going wrong. That could include errors during the startup of Docker or issues with specific Docker components.

The Docker daemon log might contain detailed error messages (at `/var/log/docker.log` or a similar location).

Uninstalling and then reinstalling Docker might help if the installation has become corrupted or misconfigured in some way.

Comment: After install successfully

"  docker was successfully installed!"

these are the next 2 lines and it fails
```
Unable to find application named 'Docker'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: BTW colima install also fails

Comment: @Uri Maybe you need to specify the path, like `/Applications/Docker.app`? I have updated the YAML code.

Comment: I run the commands one by one script connecting to the mac instance via https://github.com/lhotari/action-upterm the Docker.app is running but the docker info returns the error ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock.

Comment: the Docker.app is running but the `docker info` never succeeds

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, docker is not supported on the MacOS arm64 images.
According to [this community discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/69211) and the docs for [this github action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-docker-on-macos) it is simply not possible to run docker on these machines.